# Displaying the subcategories of a parent category with images and in a grid

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, categories

I am trying to customize a wordpress website so that a category page only shows the subcategories for that parent. I want it to show the title, description, link and image in a grid of three columns.

Woocommerce does this effortlessly with it's product categories. Can anyone guide me into achieving it with normal posts?

Comment: Are you expecting us to do the work for you?

Answer (score 0):

Pass the parent category's ID to [get_categories](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_categories/):

```
$categories=get_categories(
    array( 'parent' => $cat->cat_ID )
);
```

Afterwards loop over them and do what you please:

```
foreach ($categories as $cat) {
    //See what you've got
    var_dump($cat);
    // Or create a list
    echo '<li class="cat-tile">'.$cat->cat_name.'</li>';
}
```